# How to improve routing Speed of Nativescript Angular 5 App on Android 5 Custom Tablet?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Unfortunately our Nativescript Angular Application does not deliver a smooth user interface. The routing lags, even when release and webpack built.

Nativescript Android Version:

```
"tns-android": {
  "version": "5.0.0"
}
```

Other App dependencies:

```
"@angular/animations": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/common": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/http": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~6.1.0",
"@angular/router": "~6.1.0",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"nativescript-angular": "^6.2.0",
"nativescript-appversion": "^1.4.1",
"nativescript-downloadmanager": "^0.1.0",
"nativescript-idle": "^1.0.1",
"nativescript-nfc": "^3.0.0",
"nativescript-pager": "^8.0.2",
"nativescript-permissions": "^1.2.3",
"nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^7.4.2",
"nativescript-ripple": "2.1.0",
"nativescript-slides-d4w": "^1.7.2",
"nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
"nativescript-ui-listview": "3.7.2",
"nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~4.2.0",
"reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
"tns-core-modules": "^5.0.2",
"tns-platform-declarations": "^4.2.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
```

Routing setup (app-routing.module.ts):

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: "", redirectTo: "/initializer", pathMatch: "full" },
{ path: "initializer", component: InitializerComponent },
{ path: "intro-slider", component: IntroSliderComponent },
{ path: "plates", component: PlatesComponent },
{ path: "web-browser", component: WebBrowserComponent },
{ path: "categories", component: CategoriesComponent },
{ path: "categories/:categoryId", component: CategoriesComponent },
{ path: "products", component: ProductsComponent },
{ path: "guaranty", component: GuarantyComponent },
{ path: "locations", component: LocationsComponent }
```

The app has to be optimized for our already in use Android KIES Tablets. The hardware is currently not replaceable and in use in 300+ Real-World-Locations.

**Hardware Specifications:**

- Android 5,
- 512 MB Ram,
- 2.xGhz Quad-Core

***What we tried so far:***

- Removed lazy loading (load everything on app start instead)
- Enabled Hardware Acceleration
- Replaced all *ngIf with [visible] in templates
- Simplified template structure
- Analyzed App with Android Profiler: App peaks at about 90-100MB Ram, and 20% CPU
- Release+Webpack built

**Any ideas how to get this app to route quicker on the mentioned Hardware?**

Comment: how do you navigate from one page to another? Make sure you are not using 'clearHistory

Comment: @NarendraMongiya I navigate with this.routerExtensions.navigateByUrl("categories/" + category.categoryId);

Comment: Try this experimental feature https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/package.json#L4 but also test your application extensively once you enable the feature. I must underline that the feature can greatly improve the in-app navigation but experimental and can lead to some side effects https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/887

Comment: As a side note - please move `tns-platform-declarations` from `dependencies` to `devDependencies` otherwise the output APK will have extremely large size due to the declaration file size (which are only needed during development)

Comment: @NickIliev i tried the suggested setting, but it did not really improve the routing speed. I also moved tns-platform-declarations to devDependencies now.